# How can I guarantee data uniqueness in the YTsaurus table?

Tags: ytsaurus

I have a table with several key columns. The combination of values of those columns should be unique for every row of the table. However, duplicate entries may occur due to a human mistake, and that should be avoided.

What are the best practices here? Are there any built-in options to validate uniqueness or to automatically discard duplicate entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In YTsaurus, uniqueness constraints are a part of the schema of a table. Namely, there's the [`unique_keys` attribute](https://ytsaurus.tech/docs/en/user-guide/storage/static-schema) of the schema.

Uniqueness constraint is only applied to the table's *key.* A key is a tuple of *key columns.* Key columns are those that have their `sort_order` specified. (The columns constituting the key of a table are always a prefix of the full list of columns.)